# Remove all characters after a specific character in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i, substr

How do I get a substring from this example value:

```
 john.abc_1234
```

I want it to return `john.abc`.So basically we need to remove all the information after `_`.

More examples: 1234_abc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove part of the string in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852516/how-to-remove-part-of-the-string-in-oracle)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```
select substr('john.abc_1234', 1, instr('john.abc_1234', '_') -1)
from dual
```

> Warning: This is only guaranteed to work if your string actually has an underscore in it

**Update**

Additionally, if you are running from Oracle 10g on, you could take the Regex path, which would more powerfully handle exceptions.

Here are some links on how to do it in Oracle:

- http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html
- http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure you upvote/accept the answers that help you

Comment: @Adrian, are regexes available in 9i? I thought they were 10g plus only?

Comment: @Ben I totally missed the oracle9i tag. I guess Regex is only available from 10 on.

Comment: For the sake of having a regular expression example, here's a way with a regex: `select regexp_substr('john.abc_1234', '[^_]*')
from dual;` It assumes you want keep all up until the first underscore.

Comment: or `select regexp_replace('john.abc_1234', '(.*)_.*','\1') from dual` might be used for version 10+

Comment: I wonder whats a big deal in this question and answer. Its a simple combo of instr and substr or REGEXP_REPLACE if the version supports

Answer (score 2):

You can use via a simple combination of `substr(..)` and `instr(...)` to find the string which is free from `underscore` special charecter. Also in order to only select `_` containing strings you can make use of additional `where` clause as below

```
       select substr('john.abc_1234', 1, 
       instr('john.abc_1234', '_') -1)
      from dual where 
      instr('john.abc_1234', '_')>0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this monstrosity, when you're not sure if all your values contain the character you want to cut off your string at.

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN INSTR(field, '_') > 0
        THEN substr(field, 1, instr(field, '_') -1)
        ELSE field
    END) AS field
FROM
    dual
```

Answer (score -1):

This guy figured it out! 
http://programcsharp.com/blog/post/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server

```
SELECT
    (SELECT CAST(CAST((
        SELECT SUBSTRING(FieldToStrip, Number, 1)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(FieldToStrip) AND
            SUBSTRING(FieldToStrip, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))
    AS xml) AS varchar(MAX)))
FROM
    SourceTable
```