# How to remove part of the string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Input data:

```
abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc
```

Expected output:

```
fhj_viji.dvc
```

The part to be trimmed is not constant.

Comment: Have a look at [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF51814) and [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions080.htm#SQLRF00651) functions.

Comment: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/removing-un-wanted-text-from-strings-in-oracle/

Comment: You have not given enough information. What do you want to remove - the string `abcdef_`? The first 7 characters? What if it's `Abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc`? What if it's `abcdef_abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc`?

Comment: Add jeffery mentioned you need to provide different set of column values and expected result so solution can be provided more generic.

Answer (score 28):

Use the `REPLACE` method

```
Select REPLACE('abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc','abcde','')
```

If you want this query **for your table** :

```
Select REPLACE(column,'abcde','') from myTable
```

For **update** :

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET column = REPLACE(column,'abcde','')
```

Comment: The third argument for REPLACE is optional, and unnecessary if it is '' or NULL. You could just as easily use, `REPLACE('abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc','abcde')`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

```
select substr('abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc',instr('abcdef_fhj_viji.dvc','_')+1) from dual
```

So, Its all depends on `INSTR` function, define from which position and which occurrence, you will get the index and pass that index to `SUBSTR` to get your string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't give a lot of information I'm gonna assume some.

Let's assume you want a prefix of some string to be deleted. A good way to do that is by using Regular Expressions. There's a function called regexp_replace, that can find a substring of a string, depending on a pattern, and replace it with a different string. In PL/SQL you could write yourself a function using regexp_replace, like this:

```
function deletePrefix(stringName in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return regexp_replace(stringName, '^[a-zA-Z]+_', '');
end;
```

or just use this in plain sql like:

```
regexp_replace(stringName, '^[a-zA-Z]+_', '');
```

`stringName` being the string you want to process, and the `^[a-zA-Z]+_` part depending on what characters the prefix includes. Here I only included upper- and lowercase letters.