# Using REGEXP_SUBSTR with Strings Qualifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Getting Examples from similar Stack Overflow threads, 
[Remove all characters after a specific character in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717566/remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-pl-sql)
and 
[How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL up to a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389571/how-to-select-a-substring-in-oracle-sql-up-to-a-specific-character)

I would want to retrieve only the first characters before the occurrence of a string.

Example:

```
STRING_EXAMPLE
TREE_OF_APPLES
```

The Resulting Data set should only show only `STRING_EXAM` and `TREE_OF_AP` because `PLE` is my delimiter

Whenever i use the below `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, It gets only `STRING_` because `REGEXP_SUBSTR` treats `PLE` as separate expressions `(P, L and E)`, not as a single expression `(PLE)`.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('STRING_EXAMPLE','[^PLE]+',1,1) from dual;
```

How can i do this without using numerous INSTRs and SUBSTRs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that if you use `[^PLE]` it would match any characters other than P or L or E. You are looking for an occurence of PLE consecutively. So, use

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(colname,'(.+)PLE',1,1,null,1) 
from tablename
```

This returns the substring up to the last occurrence of PLE in the string.

If the string contains multiple instances of PLE and only the substring up to the first occurrence needs to be extracted, use

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(colname,'(.+?)PLE',1,1,null,1) 
from tablename
```

Comment: can the string have multiple occurrences of PLE in the string? if so, do you only want to extract the substring till the first occurrence?

Comment: yes that is possible. i was just testing right now and saw i have data that contained at least two `PLE` words.

Comment: Hi, i have a related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156391/performance-and-readability-of-regexp-substr-vs-instr-and-substr stemming from this.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regular expressions for this?

```
select substr(colname, 1, instr(colname, 'PLE')-1) from...
```

would be more efficient.

```
with
     inputs( colname ) as (
       select 'FIRST_EXAMPLE'  from dual union all
       select 'IMPLEMENTATION' from dual union all
       select 'PARIS'          from dual union all
       select 'PLEONASM'       from dual
     )
select colname, substr(colname, 1, instr(colname, 'PLE')-1) as result
from   inputs
;

COLNAME          RESULT
--------------   ----------
FIRST_EXAMPLE    FIRST_EXAM
IMPLEMENTATION   IM
PARIS   
PLEONASM
```

Comment: Actually, that's the current code I have, but i found it "too long" to be understood by other programmers. But tested your approach it it was actually much faster (though only a second or so). let me re-phrase the question so i can paint a better picture.

Comment: It's beyond me how any programmer can understand non-greedy matching in a regular expression but can't understand SUBSTR and INSTR. Not buying it...

Comment: Hi, i have a related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156391/performance-and-readability-of-regexp-substr-vs-instr-and-substr stemming from this. kindly take a look. thank you.