# Looking for SQL query to split the value into another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the below SQL code in order to split the value of a column into another column but it is not working the way I expected. please find the below code along with the output which I'm getting.

### Query:

```
select 
upper(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(db_attributes,'.([^\.-]+),([^\,-]+), ([^\,-]+)[so]?[\,-]',1,1,'i',1),'[so]$','') ) AS servername, db_attributes
from table_name
```

### Current Output:

```
servername                  db_attributes
HSBC                        bsprod04.hbtr.adroot.hsbc, 49465, BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01
NULL                        hkw00100308c01.hbap.adroot.hsbc, 2433, HKW00100308C01
NULL                        ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP
```

### Desired Output:

```
servername                  db_attributes
BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01          bsprod04.hbtr.adroot.hsbc, 49465, BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01
HKW00100308C01              hkw00100308c01.hbap.adroot.hsbc, 2433, HKW00100308C01
ABACOGP                     ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP
```

Regards.

Comment: Please give the content of the `table_name` table.

Comment: @Dominique table has the column name called 'db_attributes' which has all the server information, so I would like to split the end value of the column 'db_attributes' into a new column called 'servername' and would like to see the output as mentioned above.

Comment: Regular expressions are going to be much slower than `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`.

Comment: @MT0, in a table with 3 records, it won't make much difference. Besides, let's say that there are 100,000+ records in the table... How much slower is a single `regexp_substr` call going to be (per record), compared to a combination of `substr` and `instr` calls?

Comment: @PeterAbolins https://stackoverflow.com/a/41166356/1509264 tests there suggest regular expressions can be 40 times slower than string functions.

Comment: @MT0, Thanks... and as per his analysis, anchoring the regular expression properly speeds up the query significantly - even if the end result (according to him) is still slower than using string operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if the server name is always the last value in the attributes (comma-separated) list, then don't bother looking at the rest of the attributes at all.

```
SELECT 
      upper(regexp_substr(db_attributes, '[^,]+$',1,1)) AS servername
    , db_attributes
FROM
    tablename
```

**UPDATE**

And, if you want to test it, here is an [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a565/3).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6539c/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( db_attributes ) AS
SELECT 'bsprod04.hbtr.adroot.hsbc, 49465, BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'hkw00100308c01.hbap.adroot.hsbc, 2433, HKW00100308C01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( db_attributes, '\S+$' ) AS servername,
       db_attributes
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6539c/2/0)**:

```
|         SERVERNAME |                                         DB_ATTRIBUTES |
|--------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01 |  bsprod04.hbtr.adroot.hsbc, 49465, BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01 |
|     HKW00100308C01 | hkw00100308c01.hbap.adroot.hsbc, 2433, HKW00100308C01 |
|            ABACOGP |                    ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( db_attributes, INSTR( db_attributes, ' ', -1 ) + 1 ) AS servername,
       db_attributes
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6539c/2/1)**:

```
|         SERVERNAME |                                         DB_ATTRIBUTES |
|--------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01 |  bsprod04.hbtr.adroot.hsbc, 49465, BSPROD04\PTRFRDS01 |
|     HKW00100308C01 | hkw00100308c01.hbap.adroot.hsbc, 2433, HKW00100308C01 |
|            ABACOGP |                    ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP |
```