# Use regular expression in Oracle to extract a substring

Tags: regex, oracle, substring

In a table column, we have string values in the below formats,

- 0.0.0.1 /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data 329765567521139953 0
- 0.0.1.2 /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly 330064634891800799 0
- 0.0.0.1 /service/telco/gsm/telephony 32701811971 102
- 0.0.0.0  0 0 (edge case) , **EDIT** : edge case is always like this format.

If you see the format you will understand that it has four parts and each part is separated by a single space only. But in the above edge case, you need to understand that there are two spaces between `0.0.0.0` and `0 0` - where one space is the separator and another space is the second part itself. Somehow I cannot put two spaces between `0.0.0.0` and `0 0`.

- first part -> 0.0.0.1 (always in this format but digits can be
  different)
- second part -> /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data (***always in this
  format where words are separated by "/" or it could be empty. If empty then only single space is coming in place of second part. Example - as mentioned in the edge case - 0.0.0.0  0 0 , you need to understand that there are two spaces between `0.0.0.0` and `0 0`)
- third part -> unique number
- fourth part -> any number , no need to be unique

Could anyone help me write a select query in Oracle to extract two things , as mentioned below, from the string value stored in a table column,

1. second part completely
2. the word after the last "/" from the second part

**EDIT:** I want to get the output ONLY using regular expression , if possible , instead of using any string related function. I assume that using regular expression will be much faster otherwise please correct me.

Example data,

***Input*** : 0.0.0.1 /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data 329765567521139953 0

***Output:***

1. /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data
2. data

***Input*** : 0.0.1.2 /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly 330064634891800799 0

***Output:***

1. /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly
2. cycle_forward_monthly

***Input*** : 0.0.0.1 /service/telco/gsm/telephony 32701811971 102

***Output:***

1. /service/telco/gsm/telephony
2. telephony

***Input*** : `0.0.0.0  0 0`

***Output:***

1. single space (since the second part is `single space`)
2. null ( since there is no "/" in the second part)

Comment: Regarding your assumption from the question saying "I assume that using regular expression will be much faster otherwise please correct me." - you shoud read the accepted answer from  --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156391/performance-and-readability-of-regexp-substr-vs-instr-and-substr  - It is quite significant with large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-edge cases aren't difficult.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '0.0.0.1 /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data 329765567521139953 0' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '0.0.1.2 /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly 330064634891800799 0' from dual union all
  4     select 3, '0.0.0.1 /service/telco/gsm/telephony 32701811971 102' from dual union all
  5     select 4, '0.0.0.0  0 0' from dual
  6    ),
```

Extract the 2nd string (between 1st and 2nd space characters)

```
  7  temp as
  8    (select id,
  9       substr(col, instr(col, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
 10                   instr(col, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(col, ' ', 1, 1) - 1
 11             ) val
 12     from test
 13    )
```

We already have the whole 2nd string, and simple option is to use regular expression to extract the last *word*:

```
 14  select id,
 15    val,
 16    regexp_substr(val, '\w+$') last_string
 17  from temp;

        ID VAL                                                          LAST_STRING
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------------
         1 /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data                             data
         2 /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly       cycle_forward_monthly
         3 /service/telco/gsm/telephony                                 telephony
         4 null                                                         null

SQL>
```

As you can see, your *edge case* (ID = 4) is wrong - both values are `NULL`, and you said that one should be an empty space.

**However**: are you sure that data is correct? If source value contains 4 substrings separated by a single space characters, then *edge case* should actually have 3 spaces between the 1st and the 3rd substring, i.e.

```
[1st_substring] + [delimiter space] + [2nd substring space] + [delimiter space] + [3rd substring] + [delimiter space] + [4th substring]
                  -----------------   ---------------------   -----------------
                  1st space           2nd space               3rd space
```

Otherwise, the first assumption ("all substrings are separated by one space") isn't correct.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question there are two spaces between "0.0.0.0" and "0 0" but somehow for some reason its not reflecting in the question via SO editor. And I want to get the output only using regular expression instead of string related functions. I will emphasis this on the question.

Comment: I know you mentioned it; if you used CODE tags, e.g. `0.0.0.0  0 0`, spaces would have been visible. But OK, you said they are here, that's not a problem. Though, I'm not sure you understood what I tried to say in my last paragraph about **3** spaces in between (two actual spaces, as delimiters between strings + one that represents and empty string); or, we should perhaps read it as "two spaces should be treated as three spaces". As of regular expressions: note that they might (and probably will) perform *worse* on large data sets than SUBSTR + INSTR combination. Why do you insist on regex?

Comment: Okay, my bad. The edge case is different. We then need to treat it differently. I will edit my question

Comment: I thought using regular expression will be much faster. Why regular expression is slower?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156391/performance-and-readability-of-regexp-substr-vs-instr-and-substr

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't need regexp to solve this. It would be faster (especialy with bigger datasets) to use SubStr(), InStr() functions with some case expresssions:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, TXT) AS
        ( Select 1, '0.0.0.1 /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data 329765567521139953 0' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, '0.0.1.2 /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly 330064634891800799 0' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, '0.0.0.1 /service/telco/gsm/telephony 32701811971 102' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, '0.0.0.0  0 0' From Dual
        ),
```

You could create a cte (grid) that will break apart your strings (comments in code)...

```sql
    grid AS    -- logic: if no '/' characters then there is no words (PART_2)
        ( Select    ID, 
                    SubStr( TXT, 1, InStr(TXT, ' ') - 1 ) "PART_1",
                    --
                    Case When Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, '/', '')) = 0 Then ' '    -- Number of '/' characters
                    Else SubStr(TXT, InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 1) + 1, InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 2) - InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 1) - 1)
                    End "PART_2",
                    --
                    Case When Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, '/', '')) = 0 Then Null    -- Number of '/' characters
                            Else SubStr( TXT, 
                               InStr(TXT, '/', 1, ( Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, '/', '')) ) ) + 1,
                                  InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, ( Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, ' ', '')) - 1 ) ) -  -- position of second last space character
                                  InStr(TXT, '/', 1, ( Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, '/', '')) ) )        -- position of last '/' character
                                ) 
                    End "LAST_WORD",
                    --
                    Case When Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, '/', '')) = 0     -- Number of '/' characters
                         Then SubStr( Replace(TXT, '  ', ' '), 
                                      InStr(Replace(TXT, '  ', ' '), ' ', 1, 1) + 1, 
                                      InStr(Replace(TXT, '  ', ' '), ' ', 1, 2) - InStr(Replace(TXT, '  ', ' '), ' ', 1, 1) - 1
                                    )
                    Else SubStr(TXT, InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 3) - InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, 2) - 1)  
                    End "PART_3",
                    --
                    SubStr(TXT, InStr(TXT, ' ', 1, ( Length(TXT) - Length(Replace(TXT, ' ', '')) ) ) + 1) "PART_4"
          From tbl
        )
```

```sql
/*      (grid)      R e s u l t :
  ID  PART_1       PART_2                                                     LAST_WORD                PART_3                PART_4  
----  -----------  ---------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------  --------------------  --------
   1  0.0.0.1      /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data                           data                     329765567521139953    0                                                                                  
   2  0.0.1.2      /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly     cycle_forward_monthly    330064634891800799    0                                                                                  
   3  0.0.0.1      /service/telco/gsm/telephony                               telephony                32701811971           102                                                                                
   4  0.0.0.0                                                                                          0                     0       */
```

... all that you need is in the above resultset, so you can select what you want out of it...

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select ID, PART_2, LAST_WORD
From   grid
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
  ID  PART_2                                                     LAST_WORD              
----  ---------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------
   1  /event/session/telco/gsm/pp/data                           data                   
   2  /event/billing/product/fee/cycle/cycle_forward_monthly     cycle_forward_monthly  
   3  /service/telco/gsm/telephony                               telephony              
   4                                                                                    */
```

... it is a bit more code (partialy for getting all parts not just 2) but it should be faster than regexp.